# read and write from and into file

Tags: c, file, stdio

I'm trying to write a function which get numbers from the user and, put them in file and then reads them and find the minimun.
this is the code I wrote but It doesn't work at all.
can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to C.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int min_call(int, ...);


int main()
{
    int min;
    min = min_call(90,78,5,20,-1);
    printf("\n the minimum number is: %d ", min);

    min = min_call(70,40,2,-1);
    printf("\n the minimum number is: %d ", min);

    min = min_call(40,30,-1);
    printf("\n the minimum number is: %d ", min);

    return 0;
}


int min_call(int first, ...)
{
    int min;
    int currentNum;
    int i;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,first);

    FILE *fd;

    if(!(fd=fopen("min_call_file.txt","a")))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file \n");
        exit (0);
    }

    for(i = first; i>=0; i=va_arg(args, int))
    {
        fprintf(fd, "%d", i);
    }
    va_end(args);

    fseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
    min = fgetc(fd);
    do
    {
        currentNum = fgetc(fd);
        if(currentNum < min)
            min = currentNum;


    }while(!feof(fd));

    fclose(fd);
    return min;
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the file after running the program?

Comment: Your use of `while (!feof())` is [wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/3185968)

Comment: @EOF you have the most appropriate username in SO to post that comment.

Comment: @CPHPython It's noticeable whenever I need to tell somebody not to store the return value of `getchar()` to a `char`-type variable...

Comment: `fgetc(fd)` returns value in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF`, a negative number.  `min` will always end up as  `EOF`.  Exit the loop (or don't enter it) when `fgetc()` returns `EOF`.  Perhaps other issues too.

Comment: Curious, who or what text suggested using `feof(fd)` here?

Comment: yes, the file consist the first input only. the main didn't print to the screen nothing, and the program didn't exit.

Comment: Can't you just keep track of how many numbers you read from input, and use that instead of testing for EOF?

Comment: You can't read from a file stream that's opened in `"a"` mode!  You'd need either `"r"` mode or a `"+"` in the mode to be able to read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

fix like this

```
int min_call(int first, ...){
    int min;
    int currentNum;
    int i;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,first);

    FILE *fd;

    if(!(fd=fopen("min_call_file.txt","w+"))){//w : new write each call, a : Straddle the call, + : To read later
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file \n");
        exit (0);
    }

    for(i = first; i>=0; i=va_arg(args, int)){
        fprintf(fd, "%d ", i);//put space after %d because Delimiter is required
    }
    va_end(args);

    fflush(fd);//Flush the buffer and to establish  the write
    fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fscanf(fd, "%d", &min);//read integer, not character
    do {
        if(1==fscanf(fd, "%d", &currentNum) && currentNum < min){
            min = currentNum;
        }
    }while(!feof(fd));

    fclose(fd);
    return min;
}
```